# How to use MongoDB aggregate to sort through an arraylist based on a unique value?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use MongoDB to sort through the collection based on ID. However, there are multiple records with the same ID, and I would like to use the a mongodb query to sort through my arraylist and give me all the records based on if it was the most recently updated item. I do not want to remove the duplicates from the database, but I want my query to just give me the most recently updated record. Is that possible?

Comment: Would be helpful if you can provide sample data and expected output to demonstrate your desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
db.test.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort: { _id: 1, updatedOn: -1 } }
   ]
);
```

`1` indicates `ascending order` and `-1` indicates `descending order`